# Writing custom PHP code in Rules to check if a file field has a new value

Tags: 7, rules, entities, files

I need to create a condition in Rules that evaluates whether a new file has been uploaded to afile  field. The file field has an unlimited value setting and I need to send out notifications to users every time there is a new file.

EDIT
After much experimenting, I came to the conclusion that the only way to do this would be by inserting custom PHP code inside the condition that checks if a new file has been uploaded to the field and return true or false.

I stress that checking if a field is changed/updated doesn't do the job, the code needs to check if there has been a new file added. I have been reading the [Field API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7) and it might be that "columns" is what needs to be compared, but I still need a lot of help with this.

Comment: Without properly investigating I would say it should be possible with the https://drupal.org/project/rules_conditional module, doing comparisons between the old and node node.

Comment: yes, but that also covers cases where a file has been removed, unfortunately

Comment: I think it could be managed. If I get some time in the next day I'll try it out.

Comment: thank you, that would be very helpful, because I have been trying to solve this for a couple of days now and I can't seem to find a solution