# How to fire a Rule when an image is removed from Image field with unlimited values?

Tags: rules, media, files

Working with Drupal 7.58 and File Entity 2.19 and Rules 2.10

First I needed to fire a rule when saving a new file and I found a solution ([here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246587/how-to-fire-a-rule-after-adding-a-new-file-in-multi-value-field)).

Now I would like to fire a rule when an user removes an image (file) from a content (Image field with multiple values).

I can not find any event to start working after an image is removed?

EDIT 1 :

Following @Pierre.Vriens "check list approach", I have tried to create a simple rule fired when an image is removed :

```
{ "rules_verify_pictures_removed" : {
    "LABEL" : "Verify pictures removed",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "image" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules_conditional", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "node-unchanged:field-pictures" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Previous list item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "CONDITIONAL" : [
                {
                  "IF" : { "NOT list_contains" : { "list" : [ "node:field-pictures" ], "item" : [ "list-item" ] } },
                  "DO" : [
                    { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Picture has been removed.", "type" : "warning" } }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, condition is always False and I get the message even if no item has been removed (One message for each item, unchanged, added or removed)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Event like the one you are looking for. However, as illustrated in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246592/39516) to the question you linked to, you can use an approach like so:

- iterate over all field values of your field of the ***unchanged*** node.
- within each iteration step, check if the list of items in the ***changed*** node does NOT contain the field value being processed in the current iteration step ... If it is NOT contained in it anymore, it means  the values is removed.

**Note**: processing image fields in Rules is a bit special. You may have to use a token like `[node:field-pictures:file:url]` and `[list-item:file:url]`. And if they appear to be empty, then retry by adding a Rules Condition like "content is of type = article"

Comment: Thanks @Pierre for your answer. I have tried this approach that makes sense. Unfortunately, with an Image field, condition is always False if you check each item from a list of pictures. Would you please try your approach with an Image field (multi-values) and tell me if you manage to show the right message when an item is removed?

Comment: Hey @Toki, can you edit (update) your question to add an export of the Rule you tried (as you wrote in your prior comment)?

Comment: Edit OK @Pierre

Comment: @Toki can you review the "note" I added?

Comment: tokens you mentioned are not really useful here and content type is set by the event. I am still stuck unfortunately, do you know maybe how to write a rules event "When removing a file from content"?